# Kentico Task Scheduler error : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: scheduled-tasks, kentico, kentico-12

I am getting 403 forbidden error repeatedly from scheduler in production environment (Azure).

Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Exception type: System.Net.WebException Stack trace: at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) at CMS.Scheduler.SchedulingHelper.RunSchedulerRequest(String url)

REQUESTED URL: https://site_url/scheduler.ashx

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having this error in my event log aswell, and when I try to run scheduled tasks they aren't executing.